# ObjectToJsonString Capitalize First Letter

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I'm working with a webservice that is (IMO unreasonably) strict when it comes to upper/lower case on the field names.

I'm using TJSON.ObjectToJsonString and it's lowercasing all of the field names. All of the options for ObjectToJsonString surround date formatting, so I'm at a bit of a loss.

Delphi Object

```
TGeocodeServiceAddress = class(TInterfacedObject, IGeocodeServiceAddress)
private
  FAbbreviationFormat: String;
  FCountryPostalFilter: String;
  FCountry: String;
  FCounty: String;
  FState: string;
  FCity: string;
  FStreetAddress: String;
  FZip : String;
public
  {getters and setters here. Edited for brevity}

  property Zip: String read GetZip write SetZip;
  property AbbreviationFormat: String read GetAbbreviationFormat write SetAbbreviationFormat;
  property CountryPostalFilter: String read GetCountryPostalFilter write SetCountryPostalFilter;
  property Country: String read GetCountry write SetCountry;
  property County: String read GetCounty write SetCounty;
  property State: string read GetState write SetState;
  property City: string read GetCity write SetCity;
  property StreetAddress: String read GetStreetAddress write SetStreetAddress;
end;
```

JSON String

```
{  
   "abbreviationFormat":"",
   "countryPostalFilter":"",
   "country":"USA",
   "county":"PIMA",
   "state":"AZ",
   "city":"TUCSON",
   "streetAddress":"6400 E. 6th St",
   "zip":"85711"
}
```

Comment: That is hardcoded in `TJSONConverter.ConvertFieldNameToJson` method. You can either provide custom names through field attributes or write your own converter.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information. For those in the future, TJSONConverter.ConvertFieldNameToJson is in the REST.JsonReflect unit

Comment: @MartynA I think these is a bad Idea, StringReplace will work on the whole Json. With the risk of also convert Value Data. A simple automated replace can never be trusted.

Comment: @MartynA Yes you are right, but I don't expect it from Embarcadero

Comment: Like Victoria said, you can use the [`[JSONName]`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/REST.Json.Types.JSONNameAttribute) attribute to tell the convertor the desired naming of the fields. No need to write a custom convertor. For example: `[JSONName('AbbreviationFormat')] FAbbreviationFormat: String; [JSONName('CountryPostalFilter')] FCountryPostalFilter: String; ...`

Comment: @Victoria Would you mind formatting your comment into an answer? As the OP seems to be statisfied with it.

Answer (score 4):

https://community.idera.com/developer-tools/programming-languages/f/delphi-language/69467/json---converting-array-of-custom-records-to-json-text

```
uses
...
  REST.Json.Types,
...

type
  CEItem= class
  public
    [JsonName('RowName')]
    RowName: String;
    [JsonName('Name')]
    Name: String;
    [JsonName('MaxStackSize')]
    MaxStackSize: FixedUInt;
    ...
  end;
```

Comment: thanks, noticed had to add REST.Json.Types to use clause to make it work